# How to calculate Blockchain Transaction fee

Tags: blockchain

this is a small part of my block chain transaction, and I want to know how to calculate a blockchain transaction fee from this. I heard

```
    {"nonce": -1330751366, "tx":
 [{"inputs": [{"sequence": 4294967295}], "tx_index": 1939116, "hash": "5b09bbb8d3cb2f8d4edbcf30664419fb7c9deaeeb1f62cb432e7741c80dbe5ba", 
"out": [{"addr": "1KUCp7YP5FP8ViRxhfszSUJCTAajK6viGy", "tx_index": 1939116, "value": 5000200000}], "size": 168},
 {"inputs": [{"sequence": 4294967295, "prev_out": {"addr": "1EeYUCnnCDqdjNGWK9uNWQ66FQkbr6MUBa", "tx_index": 1934441, "value": 8262537860}}], 
"tx_index": 1939097, "hash": "7fec6bd918ee43fddebc9a7d976f3c6d31a61efb4f27482810a6b63f0e4a02d5", 
"out": [{"addr": "1F2o1EEREuUpjK12ifRtah6SyQK29eff7y", "tx_index": 1939097, "value": 5000000},
 {"addr": "15EFHxnebLB8vUAu8YmeGXaHrwgHwT5jJK", "tx_index": 1939097, "value": 8257537860}], "size": 259}, 
{"inputs": [{"sequence": 4294967295, "prev_out": {"addr": "14GPE4J81192XDWxsdjVp11fibninVn9pR", "tx_index": 1935211, "value": 7591252376}}],
```

Thanks is advance

Answer (score 1):

I cite the good answer of Bitcoin core developer

> No, there is not, and you cannot make such an estimate. The fee for a transaction is not dependent on the amount being transacted. That amount is completely irrelevant for fee calculation. What matters for fee calculation is the size in bytes of the data for the transaction itself. This is dependent on your wallet and which inputs it chooses to use in the transaction.
>   You could have a transaction that pays $1 but has 100 inputs. That transaction would have a very high transaction fee. Conversely, you could have a transaction that pays $100,000 but has only 1 input. That transaction would have a very low fee.
>   Because there is no relationship between the amount being sent and the transaction fee, it is impossible to give an estimate for the transaction fee given only the amount being sent.

I think this is exhaustive answer

Comment: if my comment help you, the better thank is the up-vote

Comment: sorry I'm new here. I didn't know the rule. Upvoted thanks again!